# SFTP file not found return code

Tags: bash, unix, sftp

sftp user@host:/download/xyz_str*.txt ; ret_code=$?

I save the return code into my variable **ret_code**
If it doesn't find any file its return code will be **1**
which is generic error..how can I handle this type of situation?

Comment: what situation?

Comment: If there is no file

Connecting to host...Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory
File "/download/test.txt" not found.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how we answer this: if the sftp fails, what does that mean for the rest of your code/process?  You get an error code of 1, what you should do about it depends on things you haven't said...

Comment: If doesn't connect to the sftp server I get return code 1..if I try to download some files that doesn't exit I get same 1

I have to schedule my bash script to download those files. if there is something okay, I download it

If isn't, okay, continue, but I need to know about no file found

Comment: So are you trying to distinguish between a temporary connection problem (in which case you want to retry later) and a hard, known "file not found" problem on the other end, but you can't because `sftp` returns the same error code for either case?

Comment: If you're having trouble automating the sftp command line utility, you should consider writing your own sftp client in perl, python, java, etc. There are ssh/sftp libraries for all of these languages, and it'll give you a lot more control.